# Using geolocation with react native & redux-thunk

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

currently, I'm working on a project using MapView,
so I'm struggling to use geolocation.getcurrentposition with react native and redux-thunk, so if there's anyone who can help me I will be very thankful.

Comment: I can give it a try with redux-thunk middleware not redux-saga. Lets see the code

Comment: i didn't import it to my code , so i'm using just an initial state who contains my location object where i will save my cords data,that's it bro.